# Pagination by Year

Tags: javascript

I am looking for pagination code for "years" with pure javascript. Well I have managed to create all the buttons required, but i need the logic for previous and next buttons to show  next button and hide the first button while clicking on nextButton and same viceversa for previousbutton, can someone please help me with this. Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <style>  
    .button {
        background-color: white; 
        border: none;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        text-align: center;
        color:black;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 15px;
       border-radius: 50px;
        margin :1px;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: all 0.5s;
        border: 1px solid grey;
    }
    
    .button:hover{
      padding-right: 25px;
      background-color: #008CBA; 
      color:white
    }
    .button:focus{
        background:red;
    }
    
    button.ex1:hover, button.ex1:active {color: red;}
    
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="page"></div>
    <script>
    
    var startwith = 2001;   // initialize the button starting value
    var size = 35;          // initialize the total no of buttons to be created
    var incrementBy = 1;    // increments the "startwith" by 1
    var max = 10;
    var btnMap = new Map();
    var tempMap = new Map();
    createPrevArrow();
    createBtn();
    createNextArrow();
    setOnly5Records();
    
    
    
    function createBtn(){ // > creates the total no of buttons for pagination
        
    var pageDiv = document.createElement('div');
        for(var i = 0; i < size ;i++)
        {
        
            var inc = startwith + i;
            var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
            btn.id = inc;
            btn.innerHTML = inc;
            btn.className = "button";
            btn.title = inc;
            btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
            callFunc(this.id);});       
            btnMap.set(i, btn);
            tempMap.set(i, btn);
            pageDiv.appendChild(btn);
            document.getElementById("page").appendChild(pageDiv);
        }
    }
    
    function createPrevArrow() //   > creates the previous button
    {
         var prevDiv = document.createElement('div');
         prevDiv.style.width ="10px";
         var prevArrow = document.createElement("BUTTON");
         prevArrow.id = "prev";
         prevArrow.innerHTML = "&laquo;";
         prevArrow.className = "button";
         prevArrow.onclick = callPrev;
         prevDiv.appendChild(prevArrow);
         document.getElementById("page").appendChild(prevDiv);
    }
    
    
    function createNextArrow() // > creates the next button
    {
         var nxtDiv = document.createElement('div');
         var nextArrow = document.createElement("BUTTON");
         nextArrow.id = "nxt";
         nextArrow.innerHTML = "&raquo;";
         nextArrow.className = "button";
         nextArrow.onclick = callNext;
         nxtDiv.appendChild(nextArrow);
         document.getElementById("page").appendChild(nxtDiv);
    }
    function setOnly5Records(){   //   > This method is to show only 5 buttons
    
        for(var i=5; i< size;i++)
        {
            var btn1 = btnMap.get(i);
            btn1.style.display = "none";
        }
        
    }
    function callFunc(inc)
    {
      alert(JSON.stringify(inc));
    }
    
    function callNext()   
    {
        alert("callNext");    
    }

    function callPrev()
    {
        alert("callPrev");
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

May this will help you.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style>  
    .button {
        background-color: white; 
        border: none;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        text-align: center;
        color:black;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 15px;
       border-radius: 50px;
        margin :1px;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: all 0.5s;
        border: 1px solid grey;
    }
    
    .button:hover{
      padding-right: 25px;
      background-color: #008CBA; 
      color:white
    }
    .button:focus{
        background:red;
    }
    
    button.ex1:hover, button.ex1:active {color: red;}
    
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="page"></div>
    <script>
    
    var startwith = 2001; // initialize the button starting value
    var size = 35;        // initialize the total no of buttons to be created
    var incrementBy = 1;  // increments the "startwith" initialization by 1
    var max = 10;
    var m = 5;
    var btnMap = new Map();
    var tempMap = new Map();
    createPrevArrow();
    createBtn();
    createNextArrow();
    setOnly5Records();
    
    function createBtn() { // creates the total no of buttons for pagination
        
    var pageDiv = document.createElement('div');

    for(var i = 0; i < size ;i++)
    {
            var inc = startwith + i;
            var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
            btn.id = inc;
            btn.innerHTML = inc;
            btn.className = "button";
            btn.title = inc;
            btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
                callFunc(this.id);});       
                btnMap.set(i, btn);
                tempMap.set(i, btn);
                pageDiv.appendChild(btn);
                document.getElementById("page").appendChild(pageDiv);
            }
    }
    
    function createPrevArrow() //   > creates the previous button
    {
         var prevDiv = document.createElement('div');
         prevDiv.style.width ="10px";
         var prevArrow = document.createElement("BUTTON");
         prevArrow.id = "prev";
         prevArrow.innerHTML = "&laquo;";
         prevArrow.className = "button";
         prevArrow.onclick = callPrev;
         prevDiv.appendChild(prevArrow);
         document.getElementById("page").appendChild(prevDiv);
    }
    
    
    function createNextArrow() // > creates the next button
    {
         var nxtDiv = document.createElement('div');
         var nextArrow = document.createElement("BUTTON");
         nextArrow.id = "nxt";
         nextArrow.innerHTML = "&raquo;";
         nextArrow.className = "button";
         nextArrow.onclick = callNext;
         nxtDiv.appendChild(nextArrow);
         document.getElementById("page").appendChild(nxtDiv);
    }
    function setOnly5Records(){   //   > This method is to show only 5 buttons
    
        for(var i=m; i< size;i++)
        {
            var btn1 = btnMap.get(i);
            btn1.style.display = "none";
        }
        
    }
    function callFunc(inc)
    {
      alert(JSON.stringify(inc));
    }
    
    function callNext()   
    {
        alert("callNext");
        startwith++;
        createBtn();
        setOnly5Records();
    }

    function callPrev()
    {
        alert("callPrev");
        startwith--;
        createBtn();
        setOnly5Records();
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but this way show five records more. For example, if I have already 5 buttons [2001,2002,2003,2004,2005] on the screen, when I click on next button shows the button from [2002,2003,2004,2005,2006] All I need to show one button when I click next or previous button, like if the last button is 2005, when click  next, it should show 2006 and hide 2001(1st button).

Comment: means you want to say that, when you click next there will be only 2002,2003,2004,2005,2006, single line ?